# Should I create a different ElasticSearch cluster for my different apps?

Tags: elasticsearch

If I understand properly clusters are like a databases, while nodes are like tables. So should I create a different cluster for my other apps, or am I not understanding this correctly ?

Comment: let me know if you have any followup questions on my answer, otherwise please upvote and accept answer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I understand properly clusters are like a databases, while nodes are like tables.

This is not the right analogy **and nodes are not like table**, and you can have multiple apps connects to same Elasticsearch cluster and they can interact with same or different index in the Elasticsearch cluster as one Elasticsearch cluster can holds multiple indices. and ES index is the logical grouping of the documents like table in the Sql.